# Cassandra TimedOutException and data modification for batch updates

Tags: cassandra

I execute batch update which modifies few rows within few column families. In case of TimedOutException some data could be modified, but possibly not whole set....

In order to implement compensating transaction, I would need to know what data (rows)  was modified - is there a way to find this out? Does exception contain this information?

Thanks,
Maciej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a system that can scale out means taking some trade-offs - one of these is facilitating "idempotent" operations in your application.

This means that you would either:

- assume that the data was written somewhere and that the node will
  eventually become consistent
- fire the entire contents of the write again, perhaps sleeping a given amount of time or
  at a less restrictive consistency level

A good description of this approach can be found in section 6 of Pat Helland's "Building on Quicksand" paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.1788

Comment: I cannot obtain information from cassandra what data part was modified? This is also not available in exception itself?

Comment: No - in a distributed system, the node replying to your client may not own the data, and would have "coordinated" the request to the appropriate owner and would therefore have no visibility into the status of the failure or if the message was just jettisoned due to load.

Comment: Just curious, couldn't you keep track of the timestamps in the columns that were updated and then when you go to try and re-write you compare the timestamps to see what was written or what was not written.  If the timestamp is less than you expect, then the item was not written.  If the timestamp is the same, then it was written, so do nothing.  It its greater, then another process wrote something afterward so probably don't do anything either.